# iOS 7 setting estimatedRowHeight for a tableview using autolayout does not layout the table footer view y-offset in the correct position

Tags: objective-c, ios7, swift, ios8, autolayout

For iOS 7, if I don't set the tableview's estimatedRowHeight property then the footer view displays directly underneath the tableview's last cell as expected, however not setting this property causes performance issues. If I set the estimatedRowHeight property then the table footer view either overlaps the last cell or displays several points beneath the tableview's last cell.  This is not an issue for iOS 8.